# Fixtures won't hook up with Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-cli, fixtures

I'm struggling to reproduce the official [Getting Started TodoMVC app](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/) with Ember CLI.

I'm stuck at [Using Fixtures](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/using-fixtures/). Fixtures just won't load any data.

The app runs fine with no errors and no records. I open the Ember Inspector and i see that my model exists but has no records.

[image]

Here's my app's code for you to test: [github.com/lolmaus/ember-cli-fixtures-problem-demo](https://github.com/lolmaus/ember-cli-fixtures-problem-demo/tree/1d605462ad97e257ffa3e2b0f11be35514d683a3) .

Below is the code.

### [/app/app.js](https://github.com/lolmaus/ember-cli-fixtures-problem-demo/blob/1d605462ad97e257ffa3e2b0f11be35514d683a3/app/app.js)

Unmodified Ember CLI boilerplate.

### [/app/router.coffee](https://github.com/lolmaus/ember-cli-fixtures-problem-demo/blob/1d605462ad97e257ffa3e2b0f11be35514d683a3/app/router.coffee)

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`
`import config from './config/environment'`

Router = Ember.Router.extend
  location: config.locationType

Router.map ->
  @resource 'todos', path: '/'

`export default Router`
```

### [/app/routes/todo.coffee](https://github.com/lolmaus/ember-cli-fixtures-problem-demo/blob/1d605462ad97e257ffa3e2b0f11be35514d683a3/app/routes/todo.coffee)

```
`import Ember from "ember"`

TodoRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> @store.find 'todo'


`export default TodoRoute`
```

### [/app/adapters/application.coffee](https://github.com/lolmaus/ember-cli-fixtures-problem-demo/blob/1d605462ad97e257ffa3e2b0f11be35514d683a3/app/adapters/application.coffee)

```
`import DS from "ember-data"`

FixtureAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend()

`export default FixtureAdapter`
```

### [/app/models/todo.coffee](https://github.com/lolmaus/ember-cli-fixtures-problem-demo/blob/1d605462ad97e257ffa3e2b0f11be35514d683a3/app/models/todo.coffee)

```
`import DS from 'ember-data'`

Todo = DS.Model.extend
  title:       DS.attr 'string'
  isCompleted: DS.attr 'boolean'

Todo.reopenClass
  FIXTURES:
    [
      id: 1,
      title: 'Learn Ember.js',
      isCompleted: true
    ,
      id: 2,
      title: '...',
      isCompleted: false
    ,
      id: 3,
      title: 'Profit!',
      isCompleted: false
    ]

`export default Todo`
```

PS This question is a duplicate of [Ember-cli Fixture loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231536/ember-cli-fixture-loading) . I decided to start a new one because i provided a [Github project](https://github.com/lolmaus/ember-cli-fixtures-problem-demo/tree/1d605462ad97e257ffa3e2b0f11be35514d683a3) for you to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i got this.

The resource was called `todos`, but the route file was called `todo.coffee`.

Renaming the latter to `todos.coffee` resolved the issue.